# Posting a variable to another page using a button in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use a button to POST a variable from one page in php to another. I have retrieved the variable "Class" from the table "Class" and now want to POST it to the viewmembers.php page, however am unsure how to do this.

Here is the code:

```php
<?php
    
session_start();
    
include_once('connection.php');
    
    
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM class WHERE Username = :Username");
    
$stmt->bindParam(':Username', $username);
$stmt->execute();  
    
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo("Class Code: ".$row["Class"]." <br> Username: " .$row["Username"]." <br> Subject: ".$row["SubjectName"]."<br>");

    echo("<button onclick= \"location.href='viewmembers.php'\">View Members</button><br><br>");
    
}
?>
```

I have tried using session variables, however since I have retrieved multiple rows from the table, the session variable only stores the last row that was retrieved from the table. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `location.href=...` will only cause a _GET_ request for the assigned URL. _"however am unsure how to do this."_ - create a `form`, method=post, action=url of the script you want to send it to, and stick the parameter value you need to transport into a hidden field, or make it the `value` of your button ...

Comment: @Cbroe - I don't want to use a form

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: But that _is_ really about your only option, if you directly want to post data from one page to the next. Sure, you could make an AJAX POST request in the background - but then you would still be on the first page when that request finishes, and would still have to go to the 2nd page - and then in there, pull the value out of the session, that you stored in there with your AJAX request ...

Comment: I have tried to use session variables however since I may retrieve multiple rows from the table, the session variable will only hold the last row to be retrieved.

Comment: If you don't mind using a GET, you can simply make PHP output a hyperlink containing the value as a URL parameter, like `<a href="viewmembers.php?class=abc">View Members</a>`. I'd say a GET probably makes more sense in this situation anyway, rather than POST. So `echo '<a href="viewmembers.php?class='.$row["Class"].'">View Members</a>';`

Comment: _Why_ do you want this to be a POST request in the first place? This is, apparently, a script to _view_ data(?) - so it should be requested using GET in the first place -> [When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46585/1427878)

Comment: _"however since I may retrieve multiple rows from the table, the session variable will only hold the last row to be retrieved"_ - if you want to somehow "select" multiple rows, _before_ the data is submitted, then you can't do that with a (submit) button on each row in the first place ... You'd need something like checkboxes to first _select_ the rows, and then submit that data set afterwards. (Which would be even more of a point for use an actual proper form ... which you rejected without even giving _any_ valid reason.)

Comment: X/Y problem. What do you ACTUALLY want to achieve

Comment: @mplungjan I think they just want a list of classes, with a link for each one which would open a details page about that class. Bog-standard stuff, easily solved with a hyperlink.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you just want your page to list each class, and be able to have a link to the `viewmembers.php` page, and send the class value to that page when it's clicked on.

While you mention a POST, this is generally more logical to achieve with a GET request - and simpler as well.

So instead of

```
echo("<button onclick= \"location.href='viewmembers.php'\">View Members</button><br><br>");
```

you could write

```
echo '<a href="viewmembers.php?class='.$row["Class"].'">View Members</a>';
```

which would then output a normal HTML hyperlink in the format

```
<a href="viewmembers.php?class=abc">View Members</a>
```

The `viewmembers.php` page can then read the class variable passed to it by having

```
$class = $_GET["class"];
```

in the code. It can then use that value for whatever purpose you like (e.g. by using it as a parameter in a SQL query to retrieve specific details about that class and its members, and display them).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand.

The href link uses the GET method.

For a POST method you can use some form(s) like below with the parameters you need.

```
<?php 
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
   Class Code: <?php echo $row["Class"];?>
   <br> Username: <?php echo $row["Username"];?> 
   <br> Subject: <?php echo $row["SubjectName"];?> 
   <br>

    <form method="post" action="viewmembers.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="Class" value="<?php echo $row["Class"];?>"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="Username" value="<?php echo $row["Username"];?>"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="SubjectName" value="<?php echo $row["SubjectName"];?>"> 
        <button type="submit" class="mybutton">
          View Members
         </button>
      </form>
<br>
<br>
<?php }?>`
```